# KML to Layer gives ERROR 000210 in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kmz, error-000210

I keep getting an error when trying to convert a KMZ file in ArcGIS Desktop. It shows up in google earth just fine, and I've never had problems using the KML to Layer tool before.

I keep getting error 000210, and an empty geodatabase is created.The help tool tells me this error could be due to data locking or limited access rights, but  author is open to modification of the file - says so on his website. I'm using this shapefile downloaded near the bottom of the page: http://ontariomap.webs.com/

What do you think the problem is?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the output location / output name to something else?

Comment: Yes, I've tried other locations and shorter names

Comment: Not sure whats wrong here, I get the same error. as a workaround, inside GE, right click a particular rail track, save-as. to a single KMZ. That imports. Basically convert in smaller pieces.

Comment: Ah yes that is a very reasonable solution, the conversion does work in chunks. Thank you KHibma for the workaround

Comment: I think it is  a bug of arcgis itself since FME works fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

To me Data Interoperability Extension for Arcmap is working fantastic and [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_main.htm) also seems to work. Find the FileGDB of your data as below-

[GDB LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y7m8xddrd90573/gdb.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Arc fails at this task - short filename, long filename, multipart or singlepart KML, source file open in GE or not. In my personal experience, this is simply another instance of the 10,001 inexplicable behaviors of Arc, that could be caused by any number of factors.

My experience also tells me that if your goal is to get any work done whatsoever, don't try and chase the problem down within Arc; rather, use a workaround with another suite, such as Q:

1. Open the multipart .kml in QGIS
2. Convert to .shp (simply by using Save As, by right-clicking your KML object in the left-hand sidebar)
3. Open in Arc; manipulate as needed.

While a little awkward due to cross-platforming, this procedure is reasonably simple and works. I considered writing a script, but given Arc's unreliability, the above instructions likely provide a more "direct" path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is helpful, but in my case, the antivirus was blocking the folders I was using, so I had to change the settings of the antivirus and it started to work again. Everytime I tried to convert KML to SHP, I got two errors: 00029 and 000210 and both were fixed by changing the antivirus settings

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Not sure whats wrong here, I get the same error. as a workaround,
>   inside GE, right click a particular rail track, save-as. to a single
>   KMZ. That imports. Basically convert in smaller pieces.

Answer (score 0):

if there are too many subfolders created on google earth (.kml), Arcmap won't be able to generate (.lyr) files for them all so the error appears.
the solution that worked for me {divide the subfolders on many .kml files not only one and start converting each on alone}